# Advantage of DocuSign iOS sdk

Tags: ios, docusignapi

Using the Docusign iOS SDK i integrated embedded signing into my app, but what i wanted with the SDK was flexibility to customise the signing page. What is the real advantage of using the SDK? Just give us the unique signing url? I believe we can do that even without the SDK just using REST APIs.Can't we? Am i missing something? Also please let me know how can i customise the sining page. I am just putting the signing url into a WebView and using now. I want some customisation in that page.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow :-)
Please look at [ask]
and how to create a [mcve]. This will help to get useful answers.

Comment: In general, the purpose of any SDK is simply to provide a class library in a specific language that can be used to interact with an API. It simply provides an abstraction layer such that someone familiar with the language the SDK is written in can quickly/easily develop an integration with the targeted system (in this case, DocuSign), without having to write code that constructs the JSON API requests and parses the JSON responses. Whether or not you use an SDK or manually construct API requests/responses in your code is up to you -- although using an SDK is often quicker / easier.

Comment: Thanks Kim. With the DocuSign SDK is there any way i can implement this signing using native UI elements and not UIWebView? just to give a better signing experience. I went through the DS rest api docs and the only way to do it is by obtaining the unique signing url and making the recipient view. I am looking for rest apis which would help me do this natively.

Answer (score 0):

(See my comment above for info regarding your question about using SDK versus API.)

Depending on specifically how you're wanting to customize the signing view, you may be able to achieve your goals by using the *DocuSign Signing Resource File*. You can find info about that [here](https://support.docusign.com/en/guides/docusign-signing-resource-file-v1-1).

Comment: Thanks a tonne for the reply. I understand that we can change the text of messages, dialog boxes and error messages shown during the signing process and show or hide some elements (such as images, text and dialog boxes) used during signing process. Can we also add or remove a button, set image to the start or finish button, change style of the signature tab?

Comment: In general, the Signing Resource File allows you to modify UI elements that already appear in the signing experience (ex: change a text string that appears in the UI, hide a certain button or link, etc.) -- it won't allow you to add net new (entirely custom elements) to the UI.  For example, if you wanted to add a brand new button that points to a custom URL that you define -- this isn't feasible. The guide that I linked to contains comprehensive info about specifics of what types of things are customizable.

Comment: Thanks Kim. I am customising my signing page but cannot find any way to change the background colour and text of buttons such as 'Select Style', 'Clear', 'Draw' in signature adoption page . Any help?